# call to functiolity just one time in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is method which I need to run just once when the node application is started ,I think about to put it in the server.js which is my executable file to the application but Im not sure that this is the right way to go,which other option I can use in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on when specifically it's required to be run, it may be suitable to put the function into a separate javascript file, and execute it as part of your `npm start` script within your `package.json`?

Based on your comment below stating it is a child process. It would be appropriate to execute it from the server file, but best practice would be to abstract the function out into a separate file, require it into your server file and then call it.

Comment: I need to create child process when the node application is started https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html